# Event Receiver for Social Features

Tags: event-receivers, social, rating, following, like

Are there any such things as **event receivers for social activities in SharePoint 2013**, e.g. when a user likes or rates an item? If not, are there any other ways to execute custom code when events like the aforementioned occur?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This type of functionality doesn't exist in SharePoint (yet!). However you can create it yourself by a combination of social feature development combined with remote event receivers.

[Get started developing with social features in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163864%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[How to: Create a remote event receiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Adventures with SharePoint 2013 Remote Event Receivers – Part 1 of 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/636058/Adventures-with-SharePoint-Remote-Event-Recei)